# How to give umlauts more weight in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I have a custom Analyzer for names. I'd like to give similar umlaut-matches more weight. Is that possible?

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, java.io.Reader reader) {
    VERSION = Version.LUCENE_4_9;
    final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(VERSION, reader);
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(VERSION, source);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(VERSION, result);
    result = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(result);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
}
```

Example query:
input: "Zur Mühle"
outpt (equal scores): "Zur Linde", "Zur Muehle".

Of course I'd like to get the "Zur Muehle" as top result. But how can I tell lucene to scope umlaut matches more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is use payloads to boost terms containing umlauts. Please ask for further clarification if you need more details on using payloads.